# Group price rules not working?

Tags: magento-2.0, group-price

It's quite strange because I got aware of this after a few weeks the site is online, but it looks like group price rules are not working.

If I create one (e.g. product X must have €25 price instead of €29 for group G) I can see the correct price on the catalog: when a user in group G is logged, he sees price at €25, but as he adds the item to the cart, it gets loaded at €29, and so it remains until the end of the process.

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found what was wrong. 'Disable automatic group change based on vat id' checkbox MUST be checked on customer's profile, or else I guess Magento will choose a group by itself in the moment the customer puts an item on his cart.